# AWK int comparison statements not working

Tags: bash, awk

I am using Hacker Rank challenges to teach myself BASH, and I'm in need of some advice.

I'm specifically trying to solve this challenge: [Apple and Oranges by nabila_ahmed](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/apple-and-orange/problem)

I need to read in multiple lines of `ints` separated by spaces, on multiple lines. I decided to use `awk` to do this because it seems a lot more efficient in memory storage than using `read`. (I tried a couple of solutions using `read` and they timed out, because the test cases are really big.)

Example input:

```
7 11
5 15
3 2
-2 2 1
5 -6
```

This is my first attempt in bash and it timed out:

```
row=0
while read line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
    if [ "$row" -eq 0 ]
    then
        column=0
        for n in $line; do
            if [ "$column" -eq 0 ]
            then
                housePos1=$n
            elif [ "$column" -eq 1 ]
            then
                housePos2=$n
            fi
            ((column++))
        done
        # Calculate house min and max
        if [ "$housePos1" -gt "$housePos2" ]
        then
            minHousePos=$housePos2
            maxHousePos=$housePos1
        else
            minHousePos=$housePos1
            maxHousePos=$housePos2
        fi
    elif [ "$row" -eq 1 ]
    then
        column=0
        for n in $line; do
            if [ "$column" -eq 0 ]
            then
                appleTreePos=$n    
            elif [ "$column" -eq 1 ]
            then
                orangeTreePos=$n
            fi
            ((column++))
        done
    elif [ "$row" -eq 3 ]
    then
        applesInHouse=0
        for n in $line; do
            # Calculate the apple's position
            let applePos=$((appleTreePos + n))
            # If the apple's position is within the houses position, count it
            if [ "$applePos" -ge "$minHousePos" ] && [ "$applePos" -le "$maxHousePos" ]
            then
                ((applesInHouse++))
            fi
        done
    elif [ "$row" -eq 4 ]
    then
        orangesInHouse=0
        for n in $line; do
            # Calculate the apple's position
            let orangePos=$((orangeTreePos + n))
            # If the apple's position is within the houses position, count it
            if [ "$orangePos" -ge "$minHousePos" ] && [ "$orangePos" -le "$maxHousePos" ]
            then
                ((orangesInHouse++))
            fi
        done
    fi
    ((row++))
done

echo "$applesInHouse"
echo "$orangesInHouse"
```

Here is my second attempt in bash, even more of the solutions timed out:

```
x=0;y=0;read -r s t;read -r a b;read -r m n;
for i in `seq 1 $m`; do
    if [ "$i" -lt "$m" ]
    then
        read -d\  z
    else
        read -r z
    fi
    if [ "$((a+z))" -ge "$s" ] && \
    [ "$((a+z))" -le "$t" ]
    then
        ((x++))
    fi
done
for i in `seq 1 $n`; do
    if [ "$i" -lt "$n" ]
    then
        read -d\  z
    else
        read -r z
    fi
    if [ "$((b+z))" -ge "$s" ] && \
    [ "$((b+z))" -le "$t" ]
    then
        ((y++))
    fi
done
echo $x; echo $y
```

Here's where I am at in debugging my solution using `awk`...

```
awk -v RS='[-]?[0-9]+' \
'{
    if(word==$1) { 
        counter++ 
        if(counter==1){
            s=RT
        }else if(counter==2){
            t=RT
        }else if(counter==3){
            a=RT
        }else if(counter==4){
            b=RT
        }else if(counter==5){
            m=RT
        }else if(counter==6){
            n=RT
        }else{
            counter2++
            if(counter2<=m){
                print "Apples:"
                print a+RT
                print a+RT>=s
                print a+RT<=t
                applecount++
            }
            if(counter2>m && counter2<=m+n){
                print "Oranges:"
                print b+RT
                print b+RT>=s
                print b+RT<=t
                orangecount++
            }
        }
    }else{
        counter=1
        word=$1
    }
}
END {
    print "Total Counts:"
    print applecount
    print orangecount
}
'
```

Here is the output from that script when using the sample input

```
Apples:
3
0
0
Apples:
7
1
0 <-- This is the problem! (7 is less than or equal to 11)
Apples:
6
0
0
Oranges:
20
0
0
Oranges:
9
1
0 <-- This is also a problem! (9 is less than or equal to 11)
Total Counts:
3
2
```

As you can see, I'm getting some of the wrong comparisons...

## ANSWER

(mostly courtesy of @glenn-jackman)

```
apples_oranges() {
    local s t a b m n d
    local -a apples oranges
    local na=0 nb=0
    {
        read s t
        read a b
        read m n
        read -a apples
        read -a oranges
    } < "$1"
    for d in "${apples[@]}"; do 
        (( s <= a+d && a+d <= t )) && ((na++))
    done
    echo $na
    for d in "${oranges[@]}"; do
        (( s <= b+d && b+d <= t )) && ((nb++))
    done
    echo $nb
}

apples_oranges /dev/stdin
```

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled. You want to learn `bash` but your program `awk`? Second your `awk` approach is very unconventional. You set your record separator `RS` to be any integer. This implies that your in the line `7 11` your fields are `$1=""` or `$1=" "` or `$1="\n"`. I would not say that this `RS` is the way forward.

Comment: Maybe try something like this `(NR==1){s=$1;t=$2}(NR==2){a=$1;b=$2}(NR==3){m=$1;n=$2}(NR==4){for(i=1;i<=m;i++)a[i]=$i}(NR==5){for(i=1;i<=n;i++)b[i]=$i}END{do stuff}`

Comment: Side note: I solved this with bash and it didn't time out. Reading the apples and oranges input with `read -a` worked fine.

Comment: just style: I like to write "between" conditions like `(( s <= a+d && a+d <= t )) && ((na++))` -- I think that's more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this with bash

```
apples_oranges() {
    local s t a b m n d
    local -a apples oranges
    local na=0 nb=0
    {
        read s t
        read a b
        read m n        # unused
        read -a apples
        read -a oranges
    } < "$1"
    for d in "${apples[@]}"; do 
        (( a+d >= s )) && ((na++))
    done
    echo $na
    for d in "${oranges[@]}"; do
        (( b-d <= t )) && ((nb++))
    done
    echo $nb
}

apples_oranges input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is basically my new guide for learning bash.

Comment: I slightly modified the logic so it is correct in my question. Thanks again for explaining many aspects of bash that I wasn't understanding.

Comment: @n8jadams If you want to read a guide, [this one](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) is highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

this may get you started...

```
$ awk '
   NR==1{split($0,house)} 
   NR==2{split($0,trees)} 
   NR==3{split($0,counts)} 
   NR==4{split($0,apples)} 
   NR==5{split($0,oranges)}
   END{for(i in apples) 
     if(trees[1]+apples[i]>=house[1] && trees[1]+apples[i]<=house[2]) a++; print a}' file
```

Comment: Thank you for the help with `awk`, this is also useful for me!